# Conversion of asp web chart to image

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have a graph which i have created in my asp.net C# application. Can I convert the chart to an image and store it in a folder within my application.? I know the method for storing, but can i convert the chart to image.??

Comment: How is your chart drown?

Comment: It can be bar chart, pie chart anything columns etc.

Comment: Okey, but how do you draw them? Using what functionality/library/etc.?

Comment: I am using asp chart control, using charting.. Using UI.Webcontrols. Actually I am following a youtube video. Various namespaces like collections.generic and etc are used.system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart

Answer (score 1):

Chart can save itself to image. Here is an example for controller action that returns chart image:

```
public ActionResult ChartImage()
{
    var chart = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
    .....//setup properties and data
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
         chart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
         ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
         return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png", "mychart.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, I am not using MVC. Can I know how I can do it asp.net.